# 12.9 inch iPad Simulator not presenting SpriteNodes correctly for Xcode

Tags: xcode, rotation, ios-simulator

**12.9 inch iPad Simulator not presenting SpriteNodes correctly for Xcode**

When I generate my SKScene, I use

```
ourScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

I then display several `SKShapeNodes`, e.g.,

```
let roomWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let roomHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let circleRadius = 30.0
itsStatusNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleRadius)
let circleOffsetX = 95.0
let circleOffsetY = 70.0
let circlePosX = roomWidth/2  - circleRadius - circleOffsetX
let circlePosY = roomHeight/2 - circleRadius - circleOffsetY
itsStatusNode.position = CGPoint(x: circlePosX, y: circlePosY)

toScene.addChild(itsStatusNode)
```

The above Code works for all Xcode Simulators:

```
iPad (10th Generation)
iPad Air (5th Generation)
iPad Pro (11 inch) (4th Generation)
iPad Mini (6th Generation)
```

**except** the `iPad (12.9 inch )(6th Generation)`

For example, these work for all **except** the 12.9"

```
(landscape)
circleOffsetX = 95.0
circleOffsetY = 70.0 

(portrait)
circleOffsetX = 70.0
circleOffsetY = 95.0
```

For **just** the 12.9" these work

```
(landscape)
circleOffsetX = 190.0
circleOffsetY = 145.0 

(portrait)
circleOffsetX = 150.0
circleOffsetY = 190.0
```

I have seen other reports that point other errors out for just the 12.9 inch Simulator.

**Or**, is this one of many examples when I have to upload the App **to a real Device** such as my iPad or Apple TV?

*FWIW, I only have a iPad Mini, not the 12.9 inch version*.

As always, thanks bunches for just reading this.

Comment: I said in my OP that the same offset values worked for all iPad Simulators except the 12.9 inch. The different values I gave for the 12.9 inch were very different. So I wanted to know why since the numbers were all based on UIScreen widths and heights

Comment: The thought of selecting offsets based on width & height of Simulator is totally repulsive ... so there's gotta be an optimum solution. FWIW, Mini size = 744X1133, 11" Pro size = 834X1194, Air size = 820X1180, 12.9" size = 1024X1366 for Portrait orientation.

Comment: .. or, just as awful, based on `UIDevice.current.name`

Comment: HORRAY  HOORAY  set `myScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill`  PROBLEM SOLVED